# Case when column a from tableX is present in column b of tableY

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

Below is my use case, i'm querying redshift tables, using case when but get error in case when statement.
ERROR: Statement 2 is not valid. ERROR: syntax error at or near "b"

MY SQL query:

```
CREATE TEMP TABLE TABLE1 AS
(SELECT
COL1
,COL2
,COL3
FROM XYZ_TABLE
WHERE CONDITION1
AND CONDITION2);

CREATE TEMP TABLE TABLE2 AS
(SELECT DISTINCT
COL1
FROM ABC_TABLE
WHERE CONDITION1
AND CONDITION2);


SELECT
COL1
,COL2
,COL3
,CASE WHEN (a.COL1 IN b.COL1) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS IN_TABLE_B
FROM TABLE1 a
LEFT JOIN TABLE2 b
WHERE a.COL1 = b.COL1
```

What i want to achieve:

```
TABLE1
-----------------
ID   |  NAME   | COL1
-----------------------
123  |   A    | BLA
234  |   B    | BLAA
345  |   C    | BLAH
456  |   X    | XXX
567  |   N    | FLS


TABLE2
-----------------
ID   |  COL1   | COL2
-----------------------
123  |   SKLJF    | BLA
345  |   DKLUF    | BLAH
567  |   KKBDL    | FLS
```

DESIRED OUTPUT ( IS ID IN TABLE1 PRESENT IN TABLE2, IF YES THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS COLUMN_NAME)

```
----------------------------------------------
ID   |  IN TABLE B   |
----------------------------------------------
123  |   1    | 
234  |   0    | 
345  |   1    | 
456  |   0    | 
567  |   1    |
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You wouldn't use "IN" for this even though your desire mentions the word "in"

You're performing a left join, which will have a value for b.ID where the join succeeded and a null where it failed, hence:

```
SELECT
a.ID
,CASE WHEN b.ID IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END AS IN_TABLE_B
FROM TABLE1 a
LEFT JOIN TABLE2 b
WHERE a.ID = b.ID
```

Comment: Maybe use select distinct if a given record on the left might match multiple records on the right.

Comment: It's unlikely for the case where ID columns are used, but in any case, using DISTINCT to squish the results of an unintentional cartesian product wouldn't be preferable to fixing the join conditions so that the product doesn't occur

Answer (score 1):

I might use exists logic here:

```
SELECT
    t1.ID,
    CASE WHEN EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM TABLE2 t2 WHERE t1.COL1 = t2.COL1)
         THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS IN_TABLE_B
FROM TABLE1 t1
ORDER BY t1.ID;
```

This approach is robust to a record from the first table having multiple matches.

Comment: @mayur392 . . . `exists` is a safer choice.  It does not produce duplicate rows if `table2` has duplicates.